# Writing My own class for names issue with boolean method

Tags: java, class, methods

I am writing a class for College and all it has to do is store a name in first last and middle. It also has to have a few methods one of which being "public boolean equals(Name otherName)"

Here is what I have so far

```
public class Name 
{
 private String FirstNM, MiddleNM, LastNM,Name, otherName;
 public Name(String first, String middle, String last)
{
    FirstNM = first;
    MiddleNM = middle;
    LastNM = last;
    Name = first+middle+last;
}

public String toString()
{
    return (FirstNM+", "+MiddleNM+", "+LastNM);
}

public String getFirst()
{
    return FirstNM;
}

public String getMiddle()
{
    return MiddleNM;
}

public String getLast()
{
    return LastNM;
}

public String firstMiddleLast()
{
    return (FirstNM+", "+MiddleNM+", "+LastNM);
}

public String lastFirstMiddle()
{
    return (LastNM+", "+FirstNM+", "+MiddleNM);
}

public boolean equals(Name otherName)
{
    if (otherName.equalsIgnoreCase(Name))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am having an issue with the comparing of one Name object to another Name object. the question expects me to use the equalsIgnoreCase method for this. I can't seem to get this to work. What am i doing wrong\ what can i do differently

edit: Let me clarify with the exact question from the book

4. Write a class Name that stores a person’s first, middle, and last names and provides the following methods:

·         public Name(String first, String middle, String last)—constructor. The name should be stored in the case given; don’t convert to all upper or lower case.

·         public String getFirst()—returns the first name

·         public String getMiddle()—returns the middle name

·          public String getLast()—returns the last name

·         public String firstMiddleLast()—returns a string containing the person’s full name in order, e.g., “Mary Jane Smith”.

·         public String lastFirstMiddle()—returns a string containing the person’s full name with the last name first followed by a comma, e.g., “Smith, Mary Jane”.

·         public boolean equals(Name otherName)—returns true if this name is the same as otherName. Comparisons should not be case sensitive. (Hint: There is a String method equalsIgnoreCase that is just like the String method equals except it does not consider case in doing its comparison.)

Comment: Obvious problem is that `equals` doesn't return a value in all paths - specifically won't return `false` if they values aren't equal.

Comment: Other obvious problem is that to correctly override equals you need to compare Objects and cast to String if necessary.

Comment: What use case do you have for this `equals` method?  It doesn't override `Object#equals`, so you won't get the correct functionality in data structures like `ArrayList#contains`.  I want to be sure that you *actually* need a method that takes a `Name` as a formal argument.

Comment: Please start using Java naming conventions from the beginning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`equalsIgnoreCase` is a Java String method that must be invoked on a String object. You are trying to invoke this method on a Name object, which won't work. You must invoke the helper methods within the Name class to retrieve the correct String, then invoke the `equalsIgnoreCase` method.

Here are a couple methods for comparing the entire Name string, and the 3 parts of a Name individually.

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName)
{
    return (otherName.getFirst().equalsIgnoreCase(Name.getFirst()) 
            && otherName.getMiddle().equalsIgnoreCase(Name.getMiddle())
            && otherName.getLast().equalsIgnoreCase(Name.getLast()));
}
```

Furthermore, you could have cleaner code by using the string methods you have provided.

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName)
{
    return (otherName.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Name.toString()));
}
```

Comment: I haven't run anything yet because eclipse is highlighting the equalsIgnoreCase and i am assuming that I would get an error if I tried to use the method.

Comment: Why are you still doing the if check with a `return <boolean>` expression immediately after?  Just return the boolean expression...

Comment: Eclipse is highlighting the equalsIgnoreCase because you are trying to invoke a string method on a non-String object. Please see my code provided above. Let me know if this fixes your problems. Furthermore, you should really learn how to debug your code. Google "eclipse debugging". It's a very useful tool that you should get familiar using.

Comment: The second set of code does fix my problem. Thank you for the help. I am still learning and have been more focused with getting the task completed than having it be formatted properly. I will also take your google advice.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? What have I done incorrectly? I would rather someone explain the fault in my answer, rather than blindly downvoting without an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do in the `equals` method is compare all important variables in the class. To get you started:

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName) {
    return (this.firstNm.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.firstNm) && /* rest of variables to compare */)

}
```

Technically speaking, this should be taking in an `Object` and casting it, but if your teacher said to take in  `Name` then do that I guess..

Overriding equals should really look something more like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null || ! other instanceof Name) return false;
    Name otherName = (Name) other;
    return (this.firstNm.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.firstNm) && /* rest of variables to compare */)
}
```

Comment: You want to override the `equals` method.  This means `otherName` is an `Object`.  You'll also want to check against `null`.

Comment: @Makoto I realized that, but he gave us the rules he's supposed to be following. I added that info in an edit.

Comment: I'd say not to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`; just return `false` if it's null or not an instance.  Otherwise, this answer's pretty good.

Comment: @Makoto I guess when giving advice the answer shouldn't just be "what will work" but also to show them how it should really be done.

Answer (score 1):

`equalsIgnoreCase()` is for comparing strings not for comparing objects.
In order to compare objects you need to properly override equals method. `equals()` will compare the objects for equality according to the properties you need and `hashCode()` is mandatory in order for your objects to be used correctly in `Collections`.

This is the default implementation of equals in java.lang.Object class

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

Comment: I'm just starting with java, could you possibly elaborate on what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a String with the full name, instead of Name when comparing or create a getName() method. Do this at least:

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName)
{
    String fullName = otherName.getFirst() + otherName.getMiddle() + otherName.getLast();
    if (fullName.get.equalsIgnoreCase(this.Name))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: who the heck downvoted my answer? Where in Gods name is this wrong?

Comment: I would up vote this but for the last part. It is not related to your answer and should be a comment instead.

Comment: You've got two helper methods which can provide you all of the fields that you care about in one go.  Why not use them instead?  Also, why `return true` with a `return false` outside of it?  Just return the boolean comparison.

Comment: @Quirliom agree, should have put in a comment to his question.

Comment: @Makoto I don't know what helper methods you are talking about since there is no getName() anywhere, but some methods that return the name for printing with commas between. And why do the return directly in the comparison when he has only very basic knowledge of Java? He can clearly read what I wrote and understand it, let him figure out how to improve that part by himself at least

Comment: To your point on the helper methods:  wouldn't two `Name` objects render the same information, even with the commas embedded in them?  As for the point about the returns:  it's a bit of a pet peeve of mine to see someone check a boolean condition, then return the same boolean condition back.  It's cleaner and more straightforward to return the boolean expression.

Comment: well for me it didn't make any sense to compare with the commas, since names don't have commas. Didn't think clearly I guess. And of course I agree that less is more in this case, but with the two returns it improves clarity for him I think